# solve cumulative data in Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig, cumulative-sum

I am getting some data from meter.
Example:-

```
Date          KWH
2018-12-01    50
2018-12-02    90
2018-12-03    150
```

I want to extract the actual value of KWH through Pig Code.

Expected:-

```
Date         KWH
2018-12-02   40
2018-12-03   60
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to previous record is tough in hadoop since we split the inputs and assign them to different tasks.  I think the following way would work but it's inefficient (compared to a single process reading the data sequentially).

```
A = LOAD 'test.txt' AS (a1:chararray, a2:int); 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(a1, 'y-M-d', 'UTC') as date, a2;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE AddDuration(date, 'P1D') as nextdate, -a2 as a2;
D = join B by date, C by nextdate;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE B::date as date, B::a2 + C::a2 as value;
dump E;
```